# Richfaces 4 popup editor woes

Tags: popup, editor, richfaces

Richfaces 4.2.2

I have added a button within a rich:datatable that causes a rich:popup panel to appear. The popup panel contains a `<rich:editor/>` and 2 `<h:commandButton/>`s

The button in the datatable calls a method in the backing bean to set the String to be edited, and the editor is mapped to this attribute - I know that the button is setting the String in the backing bean.

I have also added an `<h:outputText/>` to the popup panel to show the value of the String to be edited

The problems are:

1. When the editor displays, the edit panel cannot be used until the source button has been pressed a couple of time to put it into and out of source mode
2. The value of the backing bean attribute is not displayed in the editor
3. The commandButton mapped to a method in the backing bean does not call the method
4. The outputText shows the correct value the first time but it does not change on subsequent uses of the popup panel when different rows in the datatable are used

I have tried with the popup and datatable in the same for and in separate forms and have tried the separate form both inside and outside the popup panel

Here is the page

```
    <h:html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

 .
 .
 .
    <h:form id="blogForm" prependId="false">

      <rich:popupPanel  id="mp" minHeight="600" minWidth="450"  height="600" width="800" resizeable="true">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Modal Panel Title" />
        </f:facet>

        <rich:editor id="editor" toolbar="full" value="#{blogBean.currentEntry}" skin="office2003" viewMode="visual">
          <f:param name="auto_focus" value="editor" />
        </rich:editor>

        <h:outputText escape="false" value=")))#{blogBean.currentEntry}(((" />

        <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{blogBean.save}">
          <rich:componentControl target="mp" operation="hide" />  
        </h:commandButton>
        <h:commandButton value="Cancel" >
          <rich:componentControl target="mp" operation="hide" />  
        </h:commandButton>
      </rich:popupPanel>


     <a4j:commandButton value="Add new post" rendered="true" >
       <rich:componentControl target="mp" operation="show" />
     </a4j:commandButton>

     <h:panelGrid columns="1">
       <a4j:outputPanel id="panel" layout="block">                
         <rich:dataTable value="#{blogBean.entries}" columns="1" var="entry" rows="20" id="repeat" >
                 <rich:column width="800">
                     <rich:panel>
                       <f:facet name="header">
                          <a4j:commandButton value="Edit" rendered="true" oncomplete="#{rich:component('mp')}.show()">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{entry}" target="#{blogBean.currentEntry}" />
                          </a4j:commandButton>
                       </f:facet>
                       <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{entry}" />
                     </rich:panel>
             </rich:column>
         </rich:dataTable>            
       </a4j:outputPanel>            
    </h:panelGrid>   
    </h:form>
  </h:body>

</h:html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(2) and (4) are most likely because you're not actually updating their values via ajax.

1. Add an `id` attribute to your `<h:outputText/>` and `<rich:editor/>` and include those ids in the `render` attribute for the commandbutton like so :

   ```
     <a4j:commandButton value="Edit" render="editorId,outputTextId" rendered="true" oncomplete="#{rich:component('mp')}.show()">
       <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{entry}" target="#{blogBean.currentEntry}" />
     </a4j:commandButton>
   ```

   Also get rid of that markup you have in the `<h:outputText/>` and remove the `escape` attribute to be sure that is not causing the editor to choke.
2. Set your managed bean to `@ViewScoped` for peace of mind.
3. You're using a `<h:commandButton/>` in your popup. Unless this is by design, your choice here is counter-productive as this command button will trigger a full lifecycle request/postback and all that javascript you have nested in there is moot. Change those to `<a4j:commandButton/>`s. I'd suggest you remove your popup from that form and place a form **within** the popup by itself in the long run. If that doesn't change things, post your edits here to let us see exactly how you're doing it.

Comment: Many thanks @kolossus, that did the trick with the editor, it is now displaying the value and is in edit mode as soon as it appears.

Comment: Interestingly, I have tried this now in three different browser and have three different effect. Opera work as expected, the main panel is rendered and the dialog pops up in the middle of the screen with the value displayed in the editor. For Chrome the main panel and popup rendered OK but the value was not displayed in the editor. IE9 behaved as it should except that it displayed blank panel outlines at the top of the screen and when the popup was rendered it was below a large grey area

Comment: @MGB, IE doesn't count as a browser :). In chrome, can you check the JavaScript console for any warnings and also that the server actually sends the value back in the response markup?

Comment: Thanks @kolossus, I checked the javascript console for Chrome and there are no messages. I agree with you about IE but unfortunately so many people use it, my screen must work on it. I moved the popup panel to the bottom of the body section to see if that stopped the large grey area appearing but it now shows the large greay area below the main panel and then the editor below that, it looks like the z-order part is not working.I have used the IE development page to look at the generated HTML and a div with class "rf-pp-shade" and z-order 100 is the large greay area

Comment: Much as IE is a Joke, I can't believe that Richfaces popup does not work on it, so I must be doing something wrong

Answer (score -1):

To fix point no (2) use domElementAttachment="parent" in 
Example:

Comment: Thank you Victory - I will give it a try